# Extending WPF ListBoxItem for sourced items not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, listboxitem

If I create a class that extends WPF's ListBoxItem, create a list of these objects, try to bind the list to a ListBox's ItemsSource, the items will not display:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LbData, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Display}" Margin="1" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public IEnumerable lbData = new List<LbItem>();
    public IEnumerable LbData
    {
        get { return lbData; }
        set { lbData = value; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LbData = new List<LbItem> { new LbItem("a"), new LbItem("b") };
    }
}

public class LbItem : ListBoxItem
{
    public string Display { get; private set; }

    public LbItem(string v)
    {
        Display = v;
    }
}
```

I'm new to WPF and don't see why this should be an issue. TIA

Comment: can you define "will not display"? is the list box empty? or, is it displaying things, just not what you want it to?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the list box will be empty. In this simple example removing the inheritance from ListBoxItem will make it work. In the real project I wanted the items to have features of LBI.

Comment: The effect can be achieved with `ListBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(an item)` but it would be nice to know why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ItemsSource` normally is used for data-objects, and what you do there (setting the `ItemTemplate`) suggest that you should not make your object inherit from `ListBoxItem` at all, instead it should be a normal object (possibly implementing [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) if properties may change after creation). If the list changes it should implement [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx).

Because the items are already `ListBoxItems` the `DataTemplate` you set will be disregarded. There should be the following error in your Visual Studio Output-window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='LbItem'

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I'm looking for an explanation for why this does not work so I can build up my knowledge and intuition of WPF.

Comment: Ah, I was commenting on your first revision. I do not see that error when I build or run in debug mode.

Comment: It only appears in the the output window and only when the respective notifications are turned on (they should be by default), see [Debugging Data-Bindings in WPF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx) for some info.

Answer (score 0):

try setting LbData before InitializeComponent(); or Implement INotifyPropertyChanged also you probably would want to bind to an ObservableCollection

Comment: Setting LbData before InitializeComponent() does not help unfortunately. List boxes do not require ObservableCollections either.